# How to put data inside a customize state in for loop in functional component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I get the data from the API as follows:

```
[
  {
    "GroupA1": [
      {
        "code": 10,
        "name": "item1"
      },
      {
        "code": 11,
         "name": "item2"
      },
      {
        "code": 12,
         "name": "item3"
      },
      {
        "code": 13,
         "name": "item4"
      }
    ],
    "GroupA2": [
      {
        "code": 21,
         "name": "item5"
      },
      {
        "code": 20,
         "name": "item6"
      },
      {
        "code": 22,
        "name": "item7"
      },
      {
        "code": 23,
        "name": "item8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "GroupB": [
      {
        "code": 70,
        "name": "item9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "GroupC": [
      {
        "code": 50,
        "name": "item10"
      },
      {
        "code": 51,
       "name": "item11"
      },
      {
        "code": 52,
        "name": "item12"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "GroupD": [
      {
        "code": 40,
         "name": "item13"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using Redux.

After get the data in my React project and using the `for` loop and trace the data by `console.log()` , the data is displayed in the browser as follows:

```
{GroupA: Array(4)}
  GroupA: Array(4)
   0: {code: value, name: "value"}
   1: {code: value, name: "value"}
   2: {code: value, name: "value"}
   3: {code: value, name: "value"}


{GroupB: Array(1)}
  GroupB: Array(1)
   0: {code: value, name: "value"}


{GroupC: Array(3)}
  GroupC: Array(3)
   0: {code: value, name: "value"}
   1: {code: value, name: "value"}
   2: {code: value, name: "value"}


{GroupD: Array(1)}
  GroupD: Array(1)
   0: {code: value, name: "value"}
```

I want to put the data in the functional component and in the `<select>` tag which has the  `<optgroup>` tag and `<option>` tag.

I want to put data such as GroupA, GroupB, GroupC and GroupD in the `<optgroup>` tag, and also put name and code in the `<option>` tag.

My component is as follows:

```
const FunctionalComponent = () => {

const [mystate , setMyState] = useState([
    {
      title: null,
      permission: [{ name: null, code: null }],
    },
  ]);

const datas = useSelector((state) => state.datas);

const dispatch = useDispatch();


useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getDatas());


 for (var stuff in datas) {
    
      console.log( datas[stuff] );

     setMyState((t) => [...t, {title: [key]}]); //???

        value.map((v) =>
          setMyState((val) => [...val, { permission: [{ name: v.name }] ,[{ code: v.code }] }]) //???
        );
       
  }


}


return(

<div>

<select>
 <optgroup>  //show title
  <option></option>  //show name , code
 </optgroup>

</select>

</div>


)


}

export default FunctionalComponent
```

I can not display the data and they are  not recognized as separate objects in the select tag.

How do I pass the data inside state when I get the data in the `useEffect` and inside the  loop`for`, so that the `key` be placed instead title.  and  `value` that contains the code and name also be placed instead code and the name of the state?

How can I access the title, name and code of the state in JSX?

Because the way I used does not work and the data is not transferred to the state.

Thank you to those who help me!

Comment: what exactly do you need? to display correctly the select tag along with optgroup and options?

Comment: Yes, I want groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD to be included in the `<optgroup>` tag, and the code inside the `<option>` tag to be placed instead of value. and name to be placed instead of the `<option>` tag text. @Apostolos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-mclaren-bqu90v?file=/src/App.js)

```
  <select>
    {data.flatMap(obj => Object.entries(obj)).map(objArr => {
      return (
      <optgroup label={objArr[0]}>
        {objArr[1].map(ob => <option value={ob.code}>{ob.name}</option>)}
      </optgroup>
      )
    })}
  </select>
```

What it does is that it uses `flatMap` to flatten all objects into 1 array and then you can iterate this array easily.

Each entry will be a new array. First element will be the "property", the `optgroup` and the second element will fill the `option` tags.

Comment: hmm not sth specific to give you guide on. these are some key functions regarding objects and arrays that can make your work easier!

Comment: Just one more question: Can you tell me how to fill  name and code of `myState` , which are for the `permission` array object, in the `for`loop with the name and code `for` data ? I marked it in the code with a question mark!@Apostolos